# how to remove 403 error from ajax in laravel post method

Tags: ajax, laravel, server, routes, http-status-code-403

The issue with my code is if i tries to send data through ajax it give me error however my other post forms are working fine.So I am sure error must b in either route,route group or csrf feild .I have tried to put csrf feild in form,in delete button ,in input tag as hidden ,in header but nun works.Code runs perfectly fine on my computer but on server it is giving 403 Forbidden.Its been 4 days .Please provide your valuable insight and suggestions.

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">


        </style>
        <script src="{{asset('js/admin_update_ajax.js')}}"></script>
        <link href="{!! asset('css/table_layout.css') !!}" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        </head>
        <body>

        <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th style="text-align:center">Id</th>
        <th style="text-align:center">Extra Details</th>
        <th style="text-align:center">Update</th>
        <th style="text-align:center">Delete</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($details as $value): ?>
        <tr>
        <td style="font-weight: bold">{{ $value->id }}</td>

        <td>{{ $value->extra_detail }}</td>
        <td> <button class="btn btn-success btn-md" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalForm">Update</button></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        </tbody>
        </table>


        <div class="modal fade" id="modalForm" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Contact Form</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>

        </div>

        <!-- Modal Body -->
        <div id="showmessage">
        <div class="modal-body">
        <p class="statusMsg"></p>
        <div id="hidebody">
        <form role="form" id="update_form" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <div >Id:<span id="idfromtable"></span></div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="starting_date">Starting Date</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="starting_date" placeholder="Enter starting date">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ending_date">Ending Date</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="ending_date" placeholder="Enter Ending date">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="extra_details">Extra Details</label>
        <textarea  class="form-control" id="extra_detail" placeholder="Enter Ending date"></textarea>
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal Footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary submitBtn" onclick="submit_update_form()">SUBMIT</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </body

        > Blockquote
```

Java script code is

```
function submit_update_form(){

        var starting_date = document.forms["update_form"]["starting_date"].value;
        alert(starting_date);
        var ending_date = document.forms["update_form"]["ending_date"].value;
        alert(ending_date);
        var extra_detail = document.forms["update_form"]["extra_detail"].value;
        alert(extra_detail);



        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        url: "/check",
        data: {
        id:id,
        table_name:table_name,
        exam_name:exam_name,
        link:link,
        extra_detail:extra_detail

        },
        success: function(resultData) { alert(resultData) }
        });

        alert("update end from modal");
        }
```

Here is my route file

```
Route::post('/check', 'AdminController@index');
```

My controller

```
public function index()
{

    return "Data Inserted Successfully In Table ";
}
```

Comment: what error you getting can you share the error

Comment: Please share your error log?

Comment: in f12 it is sayin 403 error.

Comment: where to find log file.

Answer (score 1):

Add the below code

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': "<?php echo csrf_token() ?>"
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You have to pass `csrf-token` inside the request headers.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    url: "/check",
    data: {
        id:id,
        table_name:table_name,
        exam_name:exam_name,
        link:link,
        extra_detail:extra_detail
    }
```

Comment: Did you check in your browser network debugger tab if the CSRF is correctly sent ?